# Per-chapter bibliographies in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I'm really new in using biblatex, compile the sample placed in [Multiple bibliographies and one global bibliography - all with global labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49941/multiple-bibliographies-and-one-global-bibliography-all-with-global-labels?rq=1), but what I get is

```
  1.1 Foo

  Some text [B02x ].

  1.2 Bar

  Some text [B02y ].
```

Do not get the bibliography by chapters, or the global references.

Really not remains to be done

```
 \documentclass{report}
 \usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{references.bib}
 \begin{document}
 \chapter{First chapter}
 \section{Foo}
 Some text \cite{childs_temperature}.
 \printbibliography
 \chapter{Second chapter}
 \section{Bar}
 Some text \cite{hashemian}.
 \printbibliography
 \newpage
 \printbibliography
 \end{document}
```

And the references.bib

```
  @BOOK{childs_temperature,
  title = {Practical Temperature Measurement},
  publisher = {Butterworth - Heinemann},
  year = {2001},
  author = {Childs, Peter R N},
  address = {Great Britain},
  edition = {1},
  isbn = {0 7506 5080 X}
  }

  @PHDTHESIS{hashemian,
  author = {Hashemian, Hashem Mehrdad},
  title = {Measurements of dynamic temperatures and pressures in nuclear power plants},
  school = {{The University of Western Ontario}},
  year = {2011},
  type = {PhD {T}hesis}
  }
```

I need to obtain references by chapter and global cited references, but i don't know how compile.

Comment: The outut contains the bibtex labels of the .bib file. This looks like you didn't call bibtex to process your cited references. Did you call ``latex`` ``bibtex`` ``latex``?

Comment: Depending on the set up in your file, you may want `biber` rather than `bibtex`: we'll need an example to provide more help.

Comment: @JosephWright I think the example is the one he linked in the question...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: I understand...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It sounds like you want the `refsection` environment, detailed in Section 3.11.3 of [`biblatex`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@BOOK{childs_temperature,
  title = {Practical Temperature Measurement},
  publisher = {Butterworth - Heinemann},
  year = {2001},
  author = {Childs, Peter R N},
  address = {Great Britain},
  edition = {1},
  isbn = {0 7506 5080 X}
  }

  @PHDTHESIS{hashemian,
  author = {Hashemian, Hashem Mehrdad},
  title = {Measurements of dynamic temperatures and pressures in nuclear power plants},
  school = {{The University of Western Ontario}},
  year = {2011},
  type = {PhD {T}hesis}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
 \usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{references.bib}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{refsection}
 \chapter{First chapter}
 \section{Foo}
 Some text \cite{childs_temperature}.
 \printbibliography
 \end{refsection}

 \begin{refsection}
 \chapter{Second chapter}
 \section{Bar}
 Some text \cite{hashemian}.
 \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
 \end{refsection}

 \nocite{*}
 \printbibliography
 \end{document}
```

Just to clarify, the compilation sequence is

```
pdflatex myfile.tex
biber myfile.bcf
pdflatex myfile.tex
pdflatex myfile.tex
```

You don't have to use the file extensions if you'd prefer not to :)

If you'd prefer to use `bibtex` then use

```
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

and then run

```
pdflatex myfile.tex
bibtex myfile1-blx.aux
bibtex myfile2-blx.aux
bibtex myfile.aux
pdflatex myfile.tex
pdflatex myfile.tex
```

without the extensions if you wish.
[image: animation]

Comment: I don't know since which version, but now you use the `refsection` option of biblatex (i.e. `\usepackage[refsection=chapter]{biblatex}`) and you would not need to manually put the `refsections` in each chapter

Comment: @YuppieNetworking that's good to know, thanks!

Comment: How can we add global or combined references at the end ? \nocite{*} will add all entries in bibfile. Instead, how to combine the all references in the subbibliographies in one list at the end? –

Comment: @Anusha Did you get an answer in anyway?

Comment: Didn't know this resource, many thanks, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this affects what [YuppieNetworking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87414/per-chapter-bibliographies-in-biblatex#comment273403_87439) said, but to extend upon cmhughes's answer above, `refsection` prevents using `\ref` (or `\cref`) to reference tables or sections in different chapters (or `refsection`s).

To fix this issue, we can use `refsegment` and then use `\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment]` (inspired by [referencing to citation in a refsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303485/referencing-to-citation-in-a-refsection)).

**Edit: Please ignore this comment – I can't seem to replicate this issue in a small example <strike>or in my own working documents</strike>.**

Edit 2: this has come up again in my working documents, but that's more likely an error of my template rather than a generic error. I'm back to using the `ref segment` method.

There's additionally another reason to prefer this method over `\refsection`, but it's probably only relevant to people like me – I use a single `.bib` file, exported by my reference manager (Mendeley), for my local LaTeX work. In my overall bibliography, if I use `\nocite{*}`, that includes *every citation I have*. If there's a better way to handle this situation, please let me know! I'm sure it's a small issue.

Comment: Could you give a complete working example ?

Comment: It absolutely should not do that and indeed in a short document I just tested I could not reproduce this behaviour. Can you show us an example that reproduces the undesirable behaviour you describe? That would be a bug and should be fixed. Note that `refsegment`s are not kept separated in the same way `refsection`s are (essentially `refsegment`s just tell you where an entry was cited, but `refsection`s keep all sections completely separate). So switching from one to the other can have other implications as well.

Comment: I've now tried to replicate the issue on a small, complete working example and on my own larger project. The issue doesn't arise in either case anymore, which is a little troubling. In any case, would it be better etiquette here to delete my post or edit it to clearly mark that it is not true?

Comment: If you delete your post it will be hidden for anonymous visitors and users below a certain reputation threshold. Given that the problem is not reproducible I think it would be a good idea to hide the post from sight by deleting it (of course the note is additionally very welcome).

Comment: This issue has come up again in my working documents, so I've added another edit. Once I get a chance, I'll try to set this up in a working example again. It's likely due to my template or some other small bug.

Comment: My other issue is that I use a single `.bib` file for all my readings, so `\nocite{*}` makes everything print. This can be resolved by exporting only the `.bib` files I need, but I only intend to do that once I no longer need to add more references in my work. In case anyone is interested, [this](https://gitlab.com/jasonrwang/dissertation-tudelft-latex/tree/master) is the template I'm working off of.