# Possible to change sort order in natbib?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, subdividing, sorting

I have played a little with LaTeX lately and I really like it, it makes the document look top professional and makes structuring a report easy.

I am currently using it for a big assignment with lots of references, but I can't get `natbib` to work as I want.

What it does now is to sort by appearance which works, but I would like to have it categorized as well. I really hope this is possible, as it is a requirement.

As requested, I will try to provide a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,danish,oneside,openany]{memoir}  

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel} % danske overskrifter
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % fonte (output)
\usepackage{lmodern} % vektor fonte  

\begin{document}
% include abstract
\tableofcontents*
% include other pages  

\bibliography{./biblio/ipr}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

% include appendix
\end{document}
```

and a page could be

```
\section{Don't be evil}  

This is the first paragraph from a website.\footnote{\cite{pnp}}

This is a second paragraph with text from a book.\footnote{\cite[Part 3, chap. 2]{itp-2}}
```

In the footnote it looks like

> 1[1]
>   2[2, Part 3, chap. 2]

pnp is a website and itp-2 is a book, defined as `@misc` and `@book` in my .bib file.

```
@book{itp-2,  
  Author = {Steven Levy},  
  Edition = {1},  
  Publisher = {Simon \& Schuster},  
  Title = {In The Plex},  
  Year = {2011}  
}

@misc{pnp,  
  author = {Laszlo Bock},  
  title = {{Passion, Not Perks}},  
  howpublished = "\url{http://www.thinkwithgoogle.com/quarterly/people/laszlo-bock-people-ops.html}",  
  year = {2011},  
  note = "Bes{\o}gt den 19/12/2012"  
}
```

Is it possible to sort the book first, even though the website appears first?

This is an example of how I want it to order my references.

> **Books**
>   [4] Steven Levy. In The Plex. Simon & Schuster, 1 edition, 2011.
>
> **Web Articles**
>   [1] Mette Morsing. Corporate Branding Basics. http: //www.kommunikationsforum.dk/artikler/ corporate-branding-basics/,
>   2011. Besøgt den 17/12/2012.
>
> [3] Vlad Savov. The benefits of working at Google continue af- ter
>   death. http://www.theverge.com/2012/8/10/3232810/
>   google-employees-life-insurance, 2012.
>
> **Websites**
>   [2] Ebbe Berg. Branding. http://www.berg-marketing.dk/ branding.htm, 2012.

The numbers is the order of appearance in the text, but it is sorted after books first, then web articles and at last websites. To define what is a web article and what is a website, I believe it is possible to choose an appropriate style?

I am not very good at StackExchange layout, so I hope someone can change it to look more like a real LaTeX example. Anyway, I hope this is possible and if you know how to, it would be a great help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/14)

Comment: Are you using biblatex or bibtex? You used both tags...

Comment: I would suggest to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to show us what you have done until now. It also shows us which document class you use, `biblatex` or not, how you call your bibliography etc. This all helps us to help you ...

Comment: I am not really sure whether I use BibLaTeX or just BibTeX. I am new to LaTeX so I started out with a template and did some very minor tweaks to it.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the discussion, in http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=multbib, of the `multibbl`, `multibib`, and `splitbib` packages. Separately, since you're using `natbib`, you may want to use `unsrtnat` rather than `unsrt` as your bibliography style.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the bibliography also possible with the standard classes. The main packages to allow such a feature are:

- `multibib`
- `multibbl`
- `splitbib`

The [*UK List of TeX Frequently Asked Questions*](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?introduction=yes) has an extra article about this topic [*Multiple bibliographies?*](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-multbib)

However the customizing of the methods above are limited. To become more flexible I recommend the package [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex). You will find a lot of examples about splitting bibliographies with `biblatex`. Here are some:

- [How to split bibliography into "works cited" and "works not cited"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited)
- [Per-chapter bibliographies in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87414/per-chapter-bibliographies-in-biblatex/87439#87439)