# Add bibsection to toc (biblatex)

Tags: table-of-contents, biblatex, subdividing

I used biblatex with sucess in [Per-chapter bibliographies in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87414/problems-with-biblatex) to obtain multiple bibliographies by chapter and a global bibliograhy.

But i need add the bibsection to the toc

```
  Contents
  List of figures
  List of tables
  1. Name of the chapter one ..................... 1
     1.1 Introduction ...........................  2
     1.2 Other introduction .....................  3
     References to the chapter one...............  4
  2. Name of the chapter two ..................... 5
     2.1 Introduction ...........................  6
     2.2 Other introduction .....................  7
     References to the chapter two...............  8

  Global references .............................  10

  --------------------------------

  Chapter 1

  Name of the chapter one

  1.1 Introduction
  Bla bla (Someone, 2012)

  1.2 Other introduction (Someone, 2010)
  Bla bla

  References
  Someone, 2012, Title, IEEE.
  Someone, 2010, Title, Elsevier.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you need

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

A complete MWE follows, based on the one in your previous question :)
The compilation sequence is

```
pdflatex myfile.tex
biber myfile.bcf
pdflatex myfile.tex
pdflatex myfile.tex
```

You can omit the file extensions if you wish.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@BOOK{childs_temperature,
  title = {Practical Temperature Measurement},
  publisher = {Butterworth - Heinemann},
  year = {2001},
  author = {Childs, Peter R N},
  address = {Great Britain},
  edition = {1},
  isbn = {0 7506 5080 X}
  }

  @PHDTHESIS{hashemian,
  author = {Hashemian, Hashem Mehrdad},
  title = {Measurements of dynamic temperatures and pressures in nuclear power plants},
  school = {{The University of Western Ontario}},
  year = {2011},
  type = {PhD {T}hesis}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
 \usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{references.bib}

 \begin{document}

 \tableofcontents
 \begin{refsection}
 \chapter{First chapter}
 \section{Foo}
 Some text \cite{childs_temperature}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]
 \end{refsection}

 \begin{refsection}
 \chapter{Second chapter}
 \section{Bar}
 Some text \cite{hashemian}.
 \printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]
 \end{refsection}

 \nocite{*}
 \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
 \end{document}
```

[image: animation]

Comment: I use     \usepackage[style=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear,sorting=nty]{biblatex}
When I cite a work i use \cite{key}, i obtain Text Key 2012, text

But i need to obtain

    Text (Key, 2012) text