# Using biblatex+memoir+refsection: Why are the references included in the ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, biblatex, memoir

Consider this example taken and modified from [a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89210/add-bibsection-to-toc-biblatex):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@BOOK{childs_temperature,
  title = {Practical Temperature Measurement},
  publisher = {Butterworth - Heinemann},
  year = {2001},
  author = {Childs, Peter R N},
  address = {Great Britain},
  edition = {1},
  isbn = {0 7506 5080 X}
  }

  @PHDTHESIS{hashemian,
  author = {Hashemian, Hashem Mehrdad},
  title = {Measurements of dynamic temperatures and pressures in nuclear power plants},
  school = {{The University of Western Ontario}},
  year = {2011},
  type = {PhD {T}hesis}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{memoir}
 \usepackage[style=alphabetic,refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{references.bib}

 \begin{document}

 \tableofcontents
 % \begin{refsection}
 \chapter{First chapter}
 \section{Foo}
 Some text \cite{childs_temperature}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
 % \end{refsection}

 % \begin{refsection}
 \chapter{Second chapter}
 \section{Bar}
 Some text \cite{hashemian}.
 \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
 % \end{refsection}

 \end{document}
```

According to the documentation of biblatex, the `printbibliography` command generates a section with the references of each chapter, since the `refsection=chapter` option was used, but it should not be included in the ToC, because the `subbibliography` heading does not add it to the ToC (see the following biblatex.def extract):

```
  \defbibheading{subbibliography}[\refname]{%
    \subsection*{#1}}
  \defbibheading{subbibintoc}[\refname]{%
    \subsection*{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}}
```

However, in this example, **it is included in the ToC**.

[image]

Moreover, if the `refsection=chapter` is not used and the `\begin{refsection} \end{refsection}` parts are uncommented, the reference section is not included in the ToC, as advertised by the docs.

Another interesting clue, and maybe the **key clue** for this enigma, is that when I use the book document class instead of memoir, the references and ToC work as expected.

Can anyone explain this behavior? I'm sure that I misunderstood or did not find my way in the vast biblatex and memoir documentation.

Comment: What about `\nobibintoc` (from `memoir`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look down further in `biblatex.def` and you will find

```
\or % memoir (book)
% ....
\defbibheading{subbibliography}[\refname]{%
    \section*{#1}%
    \ifmemoirbibintoc
      {\phantomsection
       \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}
      {}%
    \if@twoside\markright{\memUChead{#1}}\fi}
```

Thus if `\memoirbibintoc` is true, it will add a reference header to the toc.

---

And that variable is tied directly to `\nobibintoc` as mentioned by `jon` (in `blx-compat.def`)

Comment: Ah! Mystery solved, mister.