# memoir & biblatex: How to suppress bibliography entry in table of contents for selected chapters?

Tags: biblatex, memoir

In my `memoir` document, I have a preface, which is defined as an unnumbered chapter, that contains a brief bibliography but I do not want that bibliography to show up in the table of contents.

When using `biblatex`, how can I control on a chapter basis, whether the bibliography shows up in the table of contents? (Before switching to `biblatex`, the printing of the bibliography and adding an entry to the table of contents was separate, so easy to control selectively.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
  @book{somebook,
    author={some author},
    title={some title},
    date={2021}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{A section}
\begin{refsection}
\textcite{somebook} showed that...
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\chapter{A section}
\begin{refsection}
\textcite{somebook} showed that...
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142412/231952
You need `\nobibintoc` before `\printbibliography`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the "big three" (the standard classes, KOMA-Script classes and `memoir`) `biblatex` tries to interface with the class as much as possible for the formatting of the bibliography heading.

For `memoir` that means that `biblatex` responds to `\nobibintoc` and `\bibintoc`. So as [Ivan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/231952/ivan) [said in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578994/memoir-biblatex-how-to-suppress-bibliography-entry-in-table-of-contents-for-s#comment1457061_578994), you can just say `\nobibintoc` before the bibliography you want to hide in the ToC. If you do this inside a `refsection` you won't even have to restore `\bibintoc` afterwards, because the effect of these commands is local.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{A section}
\begin{refsection}
\textcite{sigfridsson} showed that\dots
\nobibintoc
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\chapter{A section}
\begin{refsection}
\textcite{sigfridsson} showed that\dots
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

[image: ToC showing only one bibliography.]

If all or most of your bibliographies are `subbibliography`s you can save yourself some typing with `\DeclarePrintbibliographyDefaults` (which was added in `biblatex` v3.13 from 2019-08-17).

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclarePrintbibliographyDefaults{heading=subbibliography}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{A section}
\begin{refsection}
\textcite{sigfridsson} showed that\dots
\nobibintoc
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\chapter{A section}
\begin{refsection}
\textcite{sigfridsson} showed that\dots
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

---

With a standard class `heading=subbibliography` does not go to the ToC, so you would use `heading=subbibliography` if you don't want the bibliography to go to the ToC and `heading=subbibintoc` if you want it in the ToC.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{A section}
\begin{refsection}
\textcite{sigfridsson} showed that\dots
\nobibintoc
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\chapter{A section}
\begin{refsection}
\textcite{sigfridsson} showed that\dots
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

---

It is always possible to define a new bibliography heading to give you full control over what happens, e.g.

```
\defbibheading{mybib}[\refname]{%
  \section*{#1}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.