# Link disambiguation in document with multiple bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

In my document, there are several bibliographies with the same references. I use `biblatex` to print the bibliographies, and `hyperref` to make clickable citations. As written in the `biblatex` documentation, the link redirects to the first printed occurrence of the reference over the whole document. However, I would like the links to redirect to the bibliography table at the end of the document. How could I achieve that?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Goossens:1994:LC:561206,
        author = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
        title = {The LaTeX Companion},
        year = {1994},
        publisher = {Addison-Wesley Longman Publishing Co., Inc.}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \printbibliography[title={Front references}]
    \vfill Here is a story with references \cite{Goossens:1994:LC:561206}. \vfill
    \printbibliography[title={Back references}]
\end{document}
```

which output looks like

[image: output]

When I click the hyperlink (1), I am redirected to the "Front references", but I would like to be redirected to the "Back references". I am using PDFLaTeX and Biber from MikTeX 2.9.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142632/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303503/35864.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your document set-up there are two simple options.

1. Turn off the links for the first bibliography (and for every other bibliography except the last one you want linked).

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
   \usepackage{hyperref}

   \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

   \makeatletter
   \def\turnoffbiblinks{\let\blx@anchor\@empty}
   \makeatother

   \begin{document}
     \AtNextBibliography{\turnoffbiblinks}
     \printbibliography[title={Front references}]
     \vfill Here is a story with references \cite{sigfridsson}. \vfill
     \printbibliography[title={Back references}]
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Turn off links everywhere and turn them back on for the last bibliography.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
   \usepackage{hyperref}

   \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

   \makeatletter
   \AtBeginDocument{%
     \let\saved@blx@anchor\blx@anchor
     \let\blx@anchor\@empty
     \def\turnonbiblinks{\let\blx@anchor\saved@blx@anchor}%
   }
   \makeatother

   \begin{document}
     \printbibliography[title={Front references}]
     \vfill Here is a story with references \cite{sigfridsson}. \vfill
     \AtNextBibliography{\turnonbiblinks}
     \printbibliography[title={Back references}]
   \end{document}
   ```

This could also be done by defining a separate bibliography environment with `\defbibenvironment` instead of `\AtNextBibliography`. That might be the cleanest solution if you are looking at a document with many bibliographies.