# Create list of references at the end of each chapter with BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

What I want is that at the end of each chapter it should automatically generate a list of references.  Is that possible? and how?  (I want to use BibTeX.)  Thanks for your help.

**Update:**

I've added the follwing packages

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
```

Then in the Chapter I've added this:

```
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}        %% Literaturverzeichnis generieren
\bibliography{../bibliography/einfuehrung}
```

Then I got this:

[image]

No ref in text and then I got a whitepage and then this:

[image]

What's going wrong? I want a new section for the list of references in each chapter

**Update 2:**

**Main**

```
\documentclass[
  draft=false        % =false: Finale Version; =true: Testversion
  ,paper=a4paper          %% Papierformat A4  %%JW%% ,paper=a4
  ,ngerman           %% Das Dokument ist in neuen deutschen Recht.
  ,numbers=noenddot   % Kein Punkt nach Nummerierung im IV
  ,11pt     %% Schriftgroesse %%JW%% ,fontsize=11pt
  %,BCOR=5mm          %% 5 mm Bindekorrektur beruecksichtigen
  ,listof=totoc      %% Verzeichnisse im Inhaltsverzeichnis 
  ,bibliography=totoc % Literaturverzeichnis im Inhaltsverzeichnis
  ,index=totoc       %% Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis
 ]{book}          

 \usepackage{chapterbib}
 \include{praeambel/praeambel}   

 \begin{document}   
 \frontmatter   
 \cleardoublepage
 \tableofcontents

  \mainmatter   

  \include{content/einfuehrung}

  \end{document}
```

**content/einfuehrung.tex**

```
\chapter{Einleitung}

\section{Erl\"auterung der wichtigsten Konzepte}
 asdasd
 \section{Blubb}
 adasd
 \cite{Lidwin.2010}

 \cleardoublepage
 \bibliographystyle{alphadin}       %% Literaturverzeichnis generieren
 \bibliography{../bibliography/einfuehrung}
```

**..bibliography/einfuerhung**

```
@booklet{Lidwin.2010,
    author = {{L}idwin, {K}urt},
    year = {2010},
    title = {{D}ie {I}nstallation von {L}a{T}e{X} unter {W}indows},
    edition = {1.0},
    language = deutsch,
    publisher = {{HTWG} {K}onstanz},
    institution = {{R}echenzentrum},
    lastchecked = {05.05.2010},
 }
```

Minimal Example: http://www.file-upload.net/download-11010291/SeminarReaderMinimal.zip.html

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Package `chapterbib` should help here

Comment: Bib latex does this using something like refsection; I've answered this before somewhere, the title is something like, per-chapter bibliographies

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87414/per-chapter-bibliographies-in-biblatex

Comment: don't wanna use biblatex ... i want to use bibtex

Comment: @Felix: You want many things but do not provide some support from your side ;-) No minimal working document ...

Comment: yes you're right^^ 

What do you want to see?

Comment: added some stuff above

Comment: Please make a complete, small, minimum example, not just snippets

Comment: Added a example above.

Comment: This was crossposted to [LaTeX-community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=26840&view=unread#unread)

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html

Comment: Thanks for the link but not looking for biblatex. I need bibtex

Comment: Maybe you should properly read the whole document. And find a link that explains what a minimal working example is.

Comment: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=26793

Comment: sorry don't know what you want. Should I upload a project? I think the code above is minmal as possible

Comment: I've upladed a example project

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of errors in your code,  for example you use the class options for KOMA-Script class `scrbook`, but your code uses standard `book`.

Please read the documentation to package `chapterbib` with `texdoc chapterbib` from your console/terminal.  There you find that you first have to compile the `mwe.tex`, then use console/terminal to run `bibtex mwe-1` and `bibtex mwe-2`, then compile `mwe.tex` two times again.

With the following corrected MWE (package `filecontents` is used to have all files together in one MWE):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-1.bib}
@booklet{Lidwin.2010,
  author = {{L}idwin, {K}urt},
  year = {2010},
  title = {{D}ie {I}nstallation von {L}a{T}e{X} unter {W}indows},
  edition = {1.0},
  language = deutsch,
  publisher = {{HTWG} {K}onstanz},
  institution = {{R}echenzentrum},
  url = {http://testurl.de/test},
  lastchecked = {05.05.2010},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-2.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-1.tex}
\chapter{Einleitung}

\section{Erläuterung der wichtigsten Konzepte}
asdasd
\section{Blubb}
adasd
\cite{Lidwin.2010}

\cleardoublepage
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}       %% Literaturverzeichnis generieren
\bibliography{\jobname-1}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-2.tex}
\chapter{Einleitung 2}

\section{Erläuterung der wichtigsten Konzepte 2}
asdasd
\section{Blubb 2}
adasd
\cite{Goossens}

\cleardoublepage
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}       %% Literaturverzeichnis generieren
\bibliography{\jobname-2}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[%
  draft=false        % =false: Finale Version; =true: Testversion
 ,paper=a4           % Papierformat A4 
 ,ngerman            % neue deutsche Rechtschreibung
 ,numbers=noenddot   % Kein Punkt nach Nummerierung im IV
 ,fontsize=11pt
%,BCOR=5mm           % 5 mm Bindekorrektur beruecksichtigen
 ,listof=totoc       % Verzeichnisse im Inhaltsverzeichnis 
 ,bibliography=totoc % Literaturverzeichnis im Inhaltsverzeichnis
 ,index=totoc        % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis
]{scrbook} % book ????? <===============================================

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter   

\include{\jobname-1}
\include{\jobname-2}

\end{document}
```

you will get the following TOC:

[image]

As mentioned in the documentation there are some error messages but the result is okay. I did not try out the hints in the documentation to get rid of the errors ...  Please do that by your own.

At last I would suggest to use `biblatex`, that provides the bibliography per chapter too, but is in my eyes easier to handle and customize ...