# Global and per chapter bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using one .bib files and need to create multiple bibliographies for each chapter + one global one in the end, using biblatex (biber).
Everything works smoothly with the multiple bibliographies using refsection, however, I fail to create the global biblio.

I found a very similar problem here: [Multiple bibliographies and one global bibliography - all with global labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49941/multiple-bibliographies-and-one-global-bibliography-all-with-global-labels?rq=1) - however the solution

```
\nocite{*}
```

does not work for me as I need only those references cited (my .bib file is very large.

My example:

```
\usepackage[refsection=chapter, style=authoryear-comp,natbib=false,mcite=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
\begin{document} 
\begin{refsection}
blabla \cite{}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]
\end{refsection}

% and now the global one that should include all previously cited documents

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
\begin{refsection}
blabla \cite{}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]
\end{refsection}
```

It does neither produce a global biblio nor an entry in the toc.

Comment: Did you have a look at `chapterbib` package and incidentally at this response? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17480/6908

Answer (score 11):

I use *segments* instead of *sections*. Then you get the same and unique keys for the global bibliography, and you can get a global bibliography as well.

The final `\printbibliography` which doesn't state which segment it is for shows all segments. This works (for me), even though I don't think this is what the Biblatex documentation says. It says that the default for `segment` is "0" and segment 0 consists only of the citations outside of any environments. (If you put `segment=0` there explicitly you get no list there.)

```
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@Book{book1,
  author =       {Thor, A. U.},
  year =         2012,
  title =    {Book1}}

@Book{book2,
  author =       {Thor, A. U.},
  year =         2013,
  title =    {Book2}}

@Book{book3,
  author =       {Thor, A. U.},
  year =         2014,
  title =    {Book3}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo}
\begin{refsegment}
  \cite{book1}
  \printbibliography[segment=1, title={First bib}, heading=subbibintoc]
\end{refsegment}

\section{Bar}
\begin{refsegment}
  \cite{book2}

  \printbibliography[segment=2, title={Second bib}, heading=subbibintoc]
\end{refsegment}

\printbibliography[title={Global bib}, heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at chapterbib? Your solution looks nice (untested) but a bit complicated? Also why does do you have the refs twice in the re\begin part?

Comment: I made a cut-and-paste-error, that I've fixed now. Thanks for pointing it out, @Trefex! (Re question on some other package: No.)

Comment: +1 for segments. Do you need the `\makeatletter` stuff? I seem to be getting perfectly satisfactory results without it.

Comment: Oops! No I tricked myself there. The Biblatex documentation says similar things about `section` and `segment`, that the citations outside the environments are assigned to section/segment 0 (which is empty), but it doesn't work the same. Will edit now.

Comment: FYI, you can also use the `refsegment=<part/chapter/section/subsection>` biblatex's global option in order to **automatically create a new refsegment every part/chapter/...**

Comment: How can I make a bibliography for 2 out of 3 sections?