# How to generate the entire bibliography while using refsection for partial bibliographies?

Tags: biblatex

I would like to generate a global bibliography with all the cited entries.

Problem: the same document uses also small bibliographies for chapters with `refsection`. The final `\printbiblioraphy` does not print anything because all citations are enclosed by `refsection`.

How to generate the whole bibliography while keeping the partial ones? (i.e. print all references regardless if they are inside a `refsection` or not)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\begin{refsection}

\cite{goossens93}, \cite{lamport94}, \cite{rahtz89}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\chapter{Test Chapter Two}

\begin{refsection}
\cite{greenwade93}, \cite{patashnik88}, \cite{knuth79}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}


\printbibliography[title=The whole bibliography]

\end{document}
```

biblio.bib

```
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
    title = "The Latex Companion A",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"

}

@article{greenwade93, 
    author = "George D. Greenwade",
    title = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume = "14",
    number = "3",
    pages = "342--351",
           url=" www.ctan.org"
}

@book{knuth79,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "Tex and Metafont, New Directions in Typesetting",
    year = "1979",
    publisher = "American Mathematical Society and Digital Press",
    address = "Stanford"
}

@book{lamport94,
    author = "Leslie Lamport",
    title = "Latex: A Document Preparation System",
    year = "1994",
    edition = "Second",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{patashnik88,
    author = "Oren Patashnik",
    title = "{B}ib{T}e{X}ing.  Documentation for General {B}ib{T}e{X} users",
    year = "1988",
    howpublished = "Electronic document accompanying BibTeX
distribution"
}

@techreport{rahtz89,
    author = "Sebastian Rahtz",
    title = "A Survey of {T}ex and graphics",
    year = "1989",
    institution = "Department of Electronics and Computer Science",
    address = "University of Southampton, UK",
    number = "CSTR 89-7"
}
```

Comment: Did you try a `\nocite{*}`?

Comment: @TeXnician `nocite` would print also entries which are not cited but present in the .bib database. I just want the cited ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `biblatex`'s documentation, I'm not really sure why using `refsegment` works, but apparently it does (credit to @pst here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168728/105447)

Like:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
    title = "The Latex Companion A",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"

}

@article{greenwade93, 
    author = "George D. Greenwade",
    title = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume = "14",
    number = "3",
    pages = "342--351",
           url=" www.ctan.org"
}

@book{knuth79,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "Tex and Metafont, New Directions in Typesetting",
    year = "1979",
    publisher = "American Mathematical Society and Digital Press",
    address = "Stanford"
}

@book{lamport94,
    author = "Leslie Lamport",
    title = "Latex: A Document Preparation System",
    year = "1994",
    edition = "Second",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{patashnik88,
    author = "Oren Patashnik",
    title = "{B}ib{T}e{X}ing.  Documentation for General {B}ib{T}e{X} users",
    year = "1988",
    howpublished = "Electronic document accompanying BibTeX
distribution"
}

@techreport{rahtz89,
    author = "Sebastian Rahtz",
    title = "A Survey of {T}ex and graphics",
    year = "1989",
    institution = "Department of Electronics and Computer Science",
    address = "University of Southampton, UK",
    number = "CSTR 89-7"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\begin{refsegment}

\cite{goossens93}, \cite{lamport94}, \cite{rahtz89}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsegment}

\chapter{Test Chapter Two}

\begin{refsegment}
\cite{greenwade93}, \cite{patashnik88}, \cite{knuth79}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsegment}


\printbibliography[title=The whole bibliography]

\end{document}
```

In any case, besides working for the purpose, the use of `refsegment` instead of `refsection` seems to be advisable for the case for, if you will have a global bibliography for the book, `refsegment` will produce globally unambiguous labels, while `refsection` won't.

Comment: If you are still inside the refsegment when you call `\printbibliography`, you can use `refsegment=\therefsegment` instead of giving the number manually. That saves trouble later on.

Comment: Nice, I edited the answer accordingly. Thanks! By the way, @moewe, would you care to explain why this works? As far as I could get from `biblatex`'s documentation, `refsegment` and `refsection` differ in local/global labels, but not much more than that. But that's not really the case isn't it? Are there any other macros or options such as `\therefsegment` in this context, e.g. `segment=\all` or `segment={2,4,5}`?

Comment: `refsection` and `refsegment` differ 'only' in the local/global scope. (And in how `\printbibliography` handles them:  by default `\printbibliography` prints all refsegments, but only the current refsection.) But that is a crucial difference. Local labels mean that you can't expect the same entry to have the same label across refsections. You can't even expect the entry to exist in other refsections. Refsegments, however, are more like filters: All entries still exists (and are disambiguated etc.), you can simply mark some entries as belonging to a section and print them accordingly.

Comment: A refsegment can see entries of other refsegments (and does all that is necessary to accommodate this fact); a refsection cannot see the entries of other refsections (it therefore does not need to 'sync' up with them). In a way `segment=\all` is the default, and I don't think you can say `segment={2,4,5}` (off the top of my head, why don't you just try it?), but you can use bibfilters and bibchecks for that.

Comment: @moewe, interesting. I get better how it works now. Ingenious indeed. Thanks!