# Multiple bibliographies inside a thesis

Tags: bibliographies, thesis

As I am writing the manuscript of my PhD thesis, I am facing a `LaTeX' obstacle. Chapter 2,3 and 4 of my thesis will, each, be a copy of a published article. For so, I would like each of this chapter to end with the bibliography of the article.

I also want a bibliography at the end of thesis for the references I used in the introduction ( chapter 1), and in the chapters 5 to 7, plus the appendices.

I could use a `\includepdf` for the articles but that will remove the hyperref link inside the chapters and for so I would like to avoid that.

How can I have multiple bibliographies in a single tex document.

ps: I don't mind merging all my .bib files into one, there should be no conflict.

Comment: With `biblatex` you have the structure for multiple bibliographies built in, through the use of `refsection` or `refsegment`. Things will depend somewhat on your style of choice and on your document settings (so more info, preferably with a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be a good idea). But you can have a look at, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/202281/105447,  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168713/105447 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19326/105447.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber#Bibliographies_per_Section_or_Chapter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two Bibliographies: one for main text and one for appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98660/two-bibliographies-one-for-main-text-and-one-for-appendix)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [multibib](https://ctan.org/pkg/multibib) package to define multiple bibliographies inside the same document.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{ltex}{\TeX\ and \LaTeX\ References}
\begin{document}
References to the \TeX book \citeltex{Knuth:1991}
and to Lamport’s \LaTeX\ book, which appears
only in the references\nociteltex{Lamport:1994}.
Finally a cite to a Postscript tutorial
\cite{Adobe:1985}.
\bibliographystyleltex{alpha}
\bibliographyltex{lit}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Postscript References}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{lit}
\end{document}
```

The output will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some more detail to this answer? For example, a minimal document using [`multibib`](//ctan.org/pkg/multibib) to produce multiple bibliographies would be helpful for future visitors.