# Biblatex: dual referencing (both by end of chapter and at the end of the document) on "Clas­sicTh­e­sis" by Dr. André Miede

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, classicthesis

I have been using LaTeX the ["Clas­sicTh­e­sis"](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/) template by Dr. André Miede v. 4.6, for my dissertation/thesis document. However I require to have my references at end of each chapter as well as my "bibliography" at the end of the document/dissertation. I have tried to add commands like:

```
\begin{refsection},

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography],

\end{refsection}
```

but I keep getting error. Could it be possible someone provide me with step by step guild on how to modify this template as it contains few configuration files?

- The ["Clas­sicTh­e­sis"] produces numeric bibliography at the end of the document with respect to the global bibliography file.
- Could it be possible each chapter refer to separate bibliography file. and end of document bibliography refer to the global bibliography file.
- I could have alphabetic or the numeric references, in case of numeric, could each chapter citation have a form like  "1-12"  where 1 refer to chapter number and 12 referring to 12th reference.

Comment: Can you show us a simplified version of what you have so far (an MWE/MWEB: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)? What bibliography style are you using? How exactly would the 'global' bibliography look like? How would it be sorted? Does the citation numbering restart in each chapter, how would that work in the global bib at the end? ...

Comment: Very relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168713/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49941/35864

Comment: I can see this working for an `alphabetic` or `authoryear` bibliography. But the default bib style in `classicthesis` is `numeric` and with that style I am having some trouble figuring out what should happen. If you sort your entries with `sorting=nty` or `nyt` (and don't say `defernumbers=true`) then the global bibliography at the end would have continuous numbering (nice), but the per-chapter bibliographies may skip certain numbers (not so nice). With `sorting=nyt`/`nty` and `defernumbers=true` the per-chapter bibliographies would have continuous numbering, but ...

Comment: ... the global bibliography at the end would not have continuous numbering. (One caveat is that entries which appear in multiple per-chapter bibs may crash out of the numbering) .With `sorting=none` the situation would be similar to the situation with `defernumbers=false`: The global bib is continuous, the other bibs skip numbers (nut only if you cite the same source in different chapters, if you don't do that then the numbering will be continuous even in the per-chapter bibs). All of these options have drawbacks that make them quite unattractive on first sight.

Comment: Dear Moewe, thanks for your comments. I have modified my question to address some clarification points. As I am new with LaTeX, could you please let me know where / which file I need to modify to get the proper result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually surprisingly complicated (or maybe not so surprisingly given the fundamental complexity of such a set-up that I mentioned in the comments before your edit).

If you want separate bibliographies for each chapter, where an item will appear with a chapter prefix you need to use `refsection`s. Otherwise (with `refsegment`s) an entry cited in several chapters would get the same prefix in every chapter and so an item cited in chapters 1 and 3 would always be cited as "1-4" even in chapter 3, that would look odd. But with `refsection`s it becomes much more complicated to produce an overall bibliography at the end. Even more so when we need `labelprefix` and thus `refcontext`s. `\bibbysection` can be used to print bibliographies for all refsections one by one, but we need an additional hack to fix the `refcontext` as expected. The hack is adding a `\newrefcontext` to the internal command `\blx@refsections`. But we need to know the correct `labelprefix` here, so we need to remember it with another special command: `\savechapterrefsection`.

So you need the bit between `\makeatletter...\makeatother` in your preamble. You also need to issue

```
\newrefsection
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=\thechapter-]
\savechapterrefsection
```

directly *after* every `\chapter` command. At the end of the `\chapter` you can say

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title={\bibname\ for chapter~\thechapter}]
```

to get the per-chapter bibliography.

At the end of your document you say

```
\printbibheading[title=Overall \bibname]
\bibbysection[heading=none]
```

to print the complete bibliography.

In total

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, defernumbers, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\savechapterrefsection}{%
  \csxdef{chapter@for@refsection@\therefsection}{\thechapter}}

\def\blx@refsections{%
  \newrefcontext[labelprefix=\csuse{chapter@for@refsection@\therefsection}-]%
  \ifcsvoid{blx@dlist@entry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context}
    {}
    {\toggletrue{blx@tempa}%
     \begingroup
     \expandafter\blx@bibliography\csname blx@dlist@entry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context\endcsname}%
  \ifnum\c@refsection<\blx@maxsection
    \advance\c@refsection\@ne
    \expandafter\blx@refsections
  \else
    \iftoggle{blx@tempa}{}{\blx@warn@bibempty}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\newrefsection
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=\thechapter-]
\savechapterrefsection
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title={\bibname\ for chapter~\thechapter}]

\chapter{Two}
\newrefsection
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=\thechapter-]
\savechapterrefsection
\cite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,sigfridsson}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title={\bibname\ for chapter~\thechapter}]


\printbibheading[title=Overall \bibname]
\bibbysection[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

---

With `classicthesis` the general steps are the same, but things are made unnecessarily complicated by the complex structure of the template/package.

Assuming you have a pristine version of the template from CTAN. (Note that in general it is *extremely bad* advice to modify system installed-files from CTAN without renaming them. But `classicthesis` is more than a package and some files seem to be intended for modification, so ... it's probably fine.)

1. Go to `classicthesis-config.tex` and delete lines 85-97 reading

   ```
   \PassOptionsToPackage{%
     %backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8, %instead of bibtex
     backend=bibtex8,bibencoding=ascii,%
     language=auto,%
     style=numeric-comp,%
     %style=authoryear-comp, % Author 1999, 2010
     %bibstyle=authoryear,dashed=false, % dashed: substitute rep. author with ---
     sorting=nyt, % name, year, title
     maxbibnames=10, % default: 3, et al.
     %backref=true,%
     natbib=true % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still work)
   }{biblatex}
       \usepackage{biblatex}
   ```

   and replace them with

   ```
   \usepackage[style=numeric, defernumbers, backend=biber]{biblatex}

   \makeatletter
   \newcommand*{\savechapterrefsection}{%
     \csxdef{chapter@for@refsection@\therefsection}{\thechapter}}

   \def\blx@refsections{%
     \newrefcontext[labelprefix=\csuse{chapter@for@refsection@\therefsection}-]%
     \ifcsvoid{blx@dlist@entry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context}
       {}
       {\toggletrue{blx@tempa}%
        \begingroup
        \expandafter\blx@bibliography\csname blx@dlist@entry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context\endcsname}%
     \ifnum\c@refsection<\blx@maxsection
       \advance\c@refsection\@ne
       \expandafter\blx@refsections
     \else
       \iftoggle{blx@tempa}{}{\blx@warn@bibempty}%
       \endgroup
     \fi}
   \makeatother
   ```

   from the MWE above. Of course you can choose your favourite `biblatex` style and add more options, but it is crucial that both `defernumbers` and `backend=biber` stay and are not overwritten/contradicted by other options.
2. Remove the complete contents of `FrontBackmatter/Bibliography.tex` and replace it with just

   ```
   \printbibheading[title=Overall \bibname]
   \bibbysection[heading=none]
   ```
3. In every one of your chapters add

   ```
   \newrefsection
   \newrefcontext[labelprefix=\thechapter-]
   \savechapterrefsection
   ```

   after `\chapter` and `\label` and then add

   ```
   \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title={\bibname\ for chapter~\thechapter}]
   ```

   to the end of the chapter file where you want the bibliography to appear. If you want the bibliography in the ToC say `heading=subbibintoc` or `heading=subbibnumbered` instead of `heading=subbibliography`.
4. Make sure you compile your file with Biber and not with BibTeX. See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for help.

I tested this workflow with the files from CTAN and there are only two caveats.

- The file `AMiede_Publications.bib` is not encoded in UTF-8. Biber will choke on it, but that can be fixed by recoding the file and is likely not an issue for most people since they will use their `.bib` files.
- The code makes heavy use of `natbib` commands. If you want to use those, you need to load `biblatex` with the `natbib=true` option in step 1. See also [Is there a disadvantage to using natbib=true with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149313/35864).

The result is

[image: Bibliography of chapter 2]

for the beginning of the bibliography of chapter 2 and

[image: Overall bibliography]

for the overall bibliography.