# Combine refcontext and bibbysection

Tags: biblatex

Because i have a quite large number of literature sources (and for the sake of clarity), I chose to use separate (printed) bibliographies for the various chapters by using the `biblatex` command `\bibbysection`. Because I was not 100% convinced of that solution, I tried (for curiosity) to add a prefix to the intext citation using the chapter number, which results e.g. in [1.1]. This works fine if I use `\printbibliography` within the chapters but not anymore with `\bibbysection`.

So please help me (to understand) what's missing here. Thx in advance.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=biber, refsection=chapter, defernumbers=true, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Knuth.1986,
        author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
        year = {1986},
        title = {The \TeX book},
    }   
    @article{Einstein.1923,
        author = {Einstein, Albert},
        year = {1923},
        title = {Grundgedanken und Probleme der Relativitätstheorie},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareRefcontext{myContext}{labelprefix=\therchapter.}

\begin{document}
%\begin{refcontext}[labelprefix=\thechapter.]{altContext}

\chapter{Ch 1}
\newrefcontext{myContext}
\blindtext \cite{Knuth.1986} \cite{Einstein.1923}
%\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,section=\therefsection]

\chapter{Ch 2}
\newrefcontext{myContext}
\blindtext \cite{Einstein.1923}
%\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,section=\therefsection]


\bibbysection
%\end{refcontext}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`biblatex` usually assigns an entry to the refcontext in which it was last printed. But in `\bibbysection` this doesn't quite work because the command may be called outside the desired refcontext. (A similar issue is discussed in [Biblatex: dual referencing (both by end of chapter and at the end of the document) on "Clas­sicTh­e­sis" by Dr. André Miede](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482796/35864)) I did not manage to find a combination of refcontext assignment commands that produces the desired outcome, but since you only want to prefix citations with the chapter numbers we can actually bypass the whole `refcontext` thingy and inject the chapter numbers directly.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=biber, refsection=chapter, defernumbers=true, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\AtDataInput{%
  \blx@bbl@fieldedef{labelprefix}{\getrefnumber{refsection:\therefsection}}%
  \csuse\blx@bbl@data
  \iftoggle{blx@skipbib}
    {}
    {\ifundef\abx@field@shorthand
       {\blx@bbl@labelnumberwidth@numeric{}}
       {}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelprefix}{#1.}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Ch 1}
\blindtext \cite{nussbaum} \cite{sigfridsson}

\chapter{Ch 2}
\blindtext \cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibheading[title=Complete \bibname]
\bibbysection[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image: Complete bibliography.]

Comment: Well i hoped for a solution with built-in mechanics of biblatex, but unfortunately that doesn't seem possible atm. Nevertheless, your answer ist much appreciated.