# chapterbib with subfiles for sections

Tags: input, include, chapterbib

I'm using `chapterbib` for a long document and the creation of bibliographies for each chapter works fine.
Each chapter is in its own file that gets `included`.

Is there any option to split the chapter files by, e.g., section?
Using `input` does not work as it seems and nesting `includes` is forbidden.

Any known workaround? Could `cbunit` or `cbinput` solve this?
I'm not sure how they'd work here.

Thanks!

EDIT - MWE:

- `./main.txt`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final,titlepage]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tocbibind}

%\usepackage[rootbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{} % Internally redefine backref in order to display
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{[{\small% the pages a reference was cited
        \ifcase #1 Not cited.%
        \or Cited on page~#2.%
        \else Cited on pages #2.%
        \fi%
}]}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\include{chapters/chpt_1}

\include{chapters/chpt_2}

\chapter{Bibliography}

%Don't add a section to the toc
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}
%Don't add a title to the bibliography
\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

- `./chapters/chpt_1.tex`:

```
\chapter{Test}

\section{First}

\blindtext[10]

\cite{mathworld:AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial}

\section{Second}

\blindtext[8]

\cite{mathworld:AssociatedLegendreDifferentialEquation,mathworld:AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{../mybib}
```

- `./chapters/chpt_2.tex`

```
\chapter{Test}

\section{First}

\blindtext[10]

\cite{Weisstein}

\section{Second}

\blindtext[8]

\cite{Weissteina}

\section{Third}

\blindtext[6]

\cite{Weissteinb}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{../mybib}
```

- `mybib.bib`

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Misc{mathworld:AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial,
  Title                    = {{Associated Laguerre Polynomial. From MathWorld---A Wolfram Web Resource \url{http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial.html}}},

  Author                   = {Weisstein, Eric W.},
  Note                     = {Last visited on 16/03/2016}
}

@Misc{mathworld:AssociatedLegendreDifferentialEquation,
  Title                    = {{Associated Legendre Differential Equation. From MathWorld---A Wolfram Web Resource \url{http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLegendreDifferentialEquation.html}}},

  Author                   = {Weisstein, Eric W.},
  Note                     = {Last visited on 16/03/2016}
}

@Misc{Weisstein,
  author = {Weisstein, Eric W.},
  note   = {Last visited on 16/03/2016},
  title  = {{Wigner 3j-Symbol. From MathWorld---A Wolfram Web Resource \url{http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wigner3j-Symbol.html}}},
}

@Misc{Weissteina,
  author = {Weisstein, Eric W.},
  note   = {Last visited on 16/03/2016},
  title  = {{Wigner 6j-Symbol. From MathWorld---A Wolfram Web Resource \url{http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wigner6j-Symbol.html}}},
}

@Misc{Weissteinb,
  author = {Weisstein, Eric W.},
  note   = {Last visited on 16/03/2016},
  title  = {{Wigner 9j-Symbol. From MathWorld---A Wolfram Web Resource \url{http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wigner9j-Symbol.html}}},
}
```

To compile:

1. `pdflatex main.tex` generates the chapter `aux` files
2. `cd chapters; bibtex chpt_1.aux; bibtex chpt_2.aux; cd -`
3. comment out `sectionbib`; uncomment `rootbib`
4. `pdflatex main.tex; bibtex main.aux; pdflatex main.tex; pdflatex main.tex`

This get's us a two entry bibliograpgy in chapter 1, a three entry bibliograpgy in chapter 2, and a five entry bibliograpgy at the end.
For ease of writing - and versioning - I'd like to have each section of each chapter in its own tex-file - if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you give us a small, complete minimal example to play with?

Comment: @cmhughes added an MWE. Thanks for taking a look :)

Comment: @cmhughes any idea from your side?

Comment: I don't know if I have time (or knowledge) at the moment, I'll put a bounty on it for you :)

Comment: @cmhughes thank you! that's really kind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two packages that might help out in this situation: `subfiles` and `import`. My preference goes to `import`, so I used that package to answer your question.

To get an error free compilation I had to alter a few things in your example:

1. The package `chapterbib` is still available on CTAN, but not in my TeX distribution of MikTeX. So I replaced that by the much powerful package `biblatex` using the `biber` engine to sort the citiations.
2. In your `bib` file you used *@Misc*. That uppercase **M** isn't recognised by `biblatex`, so I changed that to the lowercase **m**.
3. References to pages can be entered as option in the `\cite` or `\parencite` commands in texts.
4. Per chapter biobliography can be obtained using the `\begin{refsection} <chapter content> \end{refsection}` structure.

The `import` package provides two commands (and aliases) to divide a long document into subdocuments. It allows for subdividing a subdocument as well. That is what I did in the next MWE's.

MWE of main.tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final,titlepage]{book}

\usepackage{import}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refer.bib}
%
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \import{chapter1/}{chapter1}
        
    \import{chapter2/}{chapter2}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
            
\end{document}
```

MWE of the first chapter (the second chapter has the same structure), stored in `./chapter1/chapter1.tex`:

```
\begin{refsection}
    
\chapter{Test}

\subimport{sections}{section1}

\subimport{sections}{section1}

\subimport{sections}{section3}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,  title=Chapter bibliography]

\end{refsection}
```

A MWE of section one as an example of the structure of all sections, stored in `./chapter1/sections/section1.tex`:

```
\section{First}

\blindtext[10]

\cite{mathworld:AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial}
```

As you can see in the provided MWE examples, there is a structure in the way chapters and sections are organised. That structure reflects the folder organisation in which those files are stored. The main document is in a top folder. The chapter files are stored in their respective subfolders (chapter1, chapter2, ...) to that top folder. The sections are stored in a subfolder sections to each chapter folder.

In the main file each chapter is imported using the command: `\import{chapterx}{chapterx}`. The first *chapterx* refers to the folder containing the .tex file *chapterx* (the second one).

The command `\subimport{sections}{sectiony}` uses the same convention: first the folder where the file is stored.

**Note** Answer is partly modified according to the comments given by Sylvain Rigal. The comment about `regsection=chapter` didn't work as expected, so the remark give in point 4 is maintained.

Comment: No need for `\begin{refsection}` environment with `biblatex`, just use the package option `refsection=chapter` for bibliography per chapter and print the chap bib with the option `segment=\therefsegment` (so no need to `\nocite{*}` which is not optimal BTW because it print all the ref in the second chapter bib and all the ref in the bib file are printed not just the cited ones), see [Multiple bibliographies and one global bibliography - all with global labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390639)

Comment: No need for `\usepackage{tocbibind}` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}` instead print the chap bib with the option `heading=subbibintoc` and the global bib with the option `heading=bibintoc`

Comment: You're right about the comments @SylvainRigal . I didn't delete / alter those lines as I was primarily focussed on the question about files and subfiles. I will alter the text / code in the MWE's in my answer according to your comments.

Comment: Erratum: it seems that it's better to use the biblatex package option `refsegment=chapter` rather than `refsection`... [details here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390639). Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, I'm facing an issue:
I've put the sections in the same directory as the chapters using `\subimport{./}{cpt1_sec1.tex}` which seems to work but I'm getting
`Package keyval Error: segement undefined. ...\therefsegment, title=Chapter bibliography]`.
A pdf is generated but with bold [mathworld:AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial] where the citation should be and with no bibliographies - neither in chapters nor at the end.
The aux file contains cite entries though.

Comment: @gothicVI I assumed Silvain had tested his comments. They can be found in the `biblatex` manual (cf. page 142), but I couldn't get that working either. So I returned to the solution given in point 4, which is also documented in the manual (cf. page 141). Excuses for not testing the comments before I changed my answer the first time (was on road).

Comment: @alchemist that sort of works - except for the global bibliography and the backrefference
EDIT: the `backref` option solves the latter

Comment: @gothicVI that's odd: I the MWE I made the chapter bibliographies and the global bibliography were printed normally. So maybe something in your full code is disrupting the output??

Comment: Indeed. I've copied your example without changes but still no global bib.
Do I need to run something on top?
I'm getting a the following in the log:
`'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.` and `22: Empty bibliography`
where line 22 is the `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]`

Comment: @gothicVI Do you get the chapter bibliographies where they are supposed to be? Let's see if we can discuss this behaviour in a chat room.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146574/discussion-between-gothicvi-and-alchemist).

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness regarding [the great answer of alchemist](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688048/262081), here a solution with chapter bibliographies and a global bibliography which print only the references cited in the document (not all the references contained in the bib file).

It uses the `refsegment=chapter` option of `biblatex` package (no need for `\begin{refsection}...\end{refsection}` environment anymore, taken from [ebosi's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390639/262081)) and the option `segment=\therefsegment` for the
`\printbibliography` command, in each chapter you want a chapbib, in order to print only the cited references of the current `refsegment` (which corresponds to a chapter in this case).

A MWE (shamefully inspired by [alchemist's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688048/262081)):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
    @Misc{ref1,
        Title                    = {Ref1 title},
        Author                   = {Ref1 text}
    }
    @Misc{ref2,
        Title                    = {Ref2 title},
        Author                   = {Ref2 text}
    }
    @Misc{ref3,
        Title                    = {Ref3 title},
        Author                   = {Ref3 text}
    }
    @Misc{ref4,
        Title                    = {Ref4 title},
        Author                   = {Ref4 text}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[refsegment=chapter, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{chapters/chapter1/chapter1.tex}
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \cite{ref1}
    \subimport{sections}{section1}
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,segment=\therefsegment, title=Chapter bibliography]
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{chapters/chapter1/sections/section1.tex}
    \section{A section}
    \cite{ref2}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{chapters/chapter2/chapter2.tex}
    \chapter{A second chapter}
    \subimport{sections}{section1}
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,segment=\therefsegment, title=Chapter bibliography]
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{chapters/chapter2/sections/section1.tex}
    \section{A section}
    \cite{ref3}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \import{chapters/chapter1}{chapter1}
    \import{chapters/chapter2}{chapter2}
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Global bibliography}]
\end{document}
```

As pointed in [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687484/chapterbib-with-subfiles-for-sections/688048#comment1707295_688048), if you store the sections tex files in the chapter folder then use `\subimport{./}{section1}` in place of `\subimport{sections}{section1}`.

Result in both cases (note that the reference `ref4` is not printed in the global bib because it is not cited in the document):

[image]